# How to model in dotnet (C#) documents with objects within arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, mongodb, object

I have the next document in spanish in my MongoDB:

```
{
"Cabecera": [{
    "NumGuia": "9672",
    "OC": "1234",
    "Fecha_Compra": "2020-03-21"
}],
"Detalle": [{
    "Cantidad": 1,
    "Obs": ""
}],
"Item": [{
    "CodAct": " ",
    "Serie": "",
    "CodInt": "",
    "Precio": "1.00",
    "UniPrecio": "USD"
}],
"Plantilla": [{
    "Nombre": "GUANTE DESCARTABLE AZUL T L",
    "Descripcion": "  ",
    "Naturaleza": 2,
    "Peso": "0.0000",
    "UniPeso": 1,
    "CodBar": "",
    "NumPar": "1000006585",
    "Caja": false,
    "stockCri": 1000,
    "stockMax": 4000,
    "Precio": "1.00",
    "UniMonetaria": "USD",
    "NumPartCli": "",
    "Critica": false,
    "Epp": false,
    "Calibracion": false
}],
"Marca": [{
    "Nombre": "ANSELL"
}],
"Categoria": [{
    "Nombre": "EPP",
    "Tipo": 2
}],
"SubCategoria": [{
    "Nombre": "ADHESIVO"
}]
```

which indicates that for each fix, at position zero there is an object with attributes.
my problem is being able to create the "model" class within my web api project in dotnet core.
Since I can't model the arrays and objects within each array, I can't use the CRUD I have to do with this Web API...

Any help knowing how to model this document in my model.cs class?

PD: here's what I currently have in my class mode.cs:

```
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public BsonIdAttribute id { get; set; }

    //array cabecera
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Array)]
    public Array Cabecera { get; set; }
        public string NumGuia { get; set; }
        public string OC { get; set; }
        public string Fecha_Compra { get; set; }

    //array Detalle
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Array)]
    public Array Detalle { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public string Obs { get; set; }

    //array Item
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Array)]
    public Array Item { get; set; }
        public string CodAct { get; set; }
        public string Serie { get; set; }
        public string CodInt { get; set; }
        public string Precio { get; set; }
        public string UniPrecio { get; set; }

    //array Plantilla
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Array)]
    public Array Plantilla { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public int Naturaleza { get; set; }
        public string Peso { get; set; }
        public int UniPeso { get; set; }
        public string CodBar { get; set; }
        public string NumPar { get; set; }
        public bool Caja { get; set; }
        public int stockCri { get; set; }
        public int stockMax { get; set; }
        public string PrecioP { get; set; }
        public string UniMonetaria { get; set; }
        public string NumPartCli { get; set; }
        public bool Critica { get; set; }
        public bool Epp { get; set; }
        public bool Calibracion { get; set; }

    //array Marca
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Array)]
    public Array Marca { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

    //array Categoria
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Array)]
    public Array Categoria { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Tipo { get; set; }

    //array SubCategoria
    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Array)]
    public Array SubCategoria { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using (for example) `Item[]` and not `Array`?

Comment: I can't see `Id` in your data... Also, I can't easily get my brain around the whole model that you have posted here. Why don't you simplify your model for the purposes of the question, with limited nested objects, and ask again (or edit your question). It will be easier for people to help you